# I have a server under Linux OS, I delete the tomcat folder, how to restore it?

Tags: linux, tomcat, restore

I have a server under Linux OS, I delete the tomcat folder, how to restore it? 
this folder contain all my project under webapps and my tomcat configuration
please help me to restore this folder please I forget what configuration I did it to re configured again

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted it using `rm -rf /path/to/your/folder` then it's basically gone. If you deleted it via the GUI (if you even have that installed) then it may be in your recycling bin.

Comment: i delete it by (rm -fr *) remotely under linux, how can i restore it

Comment: For all intents and purposes, it's gone. Because of the way linux filesystems are structured, file can't be recovered (someone correct me if I'm wrong)